# Accumulate the value of a SQL field when i store the same primary key

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm new in Stack Overflow, I searched the world about this problem, but no success.

I have an exam very soon about this program, which is a very basic computer part store written in java with like 'Clients', 'Productos' and 'Sales'.

Now, the only problem is on the 'Product' and 'Sales' tables. These two tables have a SQL 'Quantity' field on each table, I have to be able to store the quantity of a product every time I insert a duplicated primary key without getting SQL primary key duplicate errors.

This is my code:

```
void guardar(){
        conectar cc= new conectar();
        Connection cn= cc.conexion();

        String sql="";
        cod=cli_dni.getText();
        ape=cli_ap.getText();
        nomb=cli_nom.getText();
        tel=cli_tel.getText();
        String ivarespon=combocli_iva.getSelectedItem().toString();
        sql="INSERT INTO clientes (cli_dni, cli_nom, cli_ap, cli_tel, cli_iva) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        if(ivarespon.equals("Seleccione")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a correct iva taxpayer",
                  "ERROR_MESSAGE", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
        try {
        PreparedStatement psd= cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        psd.setString(1,cod);
        psd.setString(2,ape);
        psd.setString(3,nomb);
        psd.setString(4,tel);
        psd.setString(5,ivarespon);
        int n=psd.executeUpdate();
        if(n>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Success!");
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" ,
                      "ERROR_MESSAGE", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        cargar("");
        limpiar();
        }
    }
```

And for the 'Sales' table, everytime when I make a sale of a product, I have to be able to subtract the quantity of the Product's 'Quantity' field of my database as well. The java method to save data into my 'Sale' sql table has the same code like this one.

My mind is going crazy about this duplicate primary key error, any help is more than welcomed and I'm thankful for it.

Comment: Why would you insert something with a key that is already taken? If a value of an entry in your database changes, use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`!

Comment: This is a variant on the upsert problem; knowing that will help you find better info. Short version: Update to PostgreSQL 9.5 and use `ON CONFLICT UPDATE`

Answer (score 1):

In 9.5 you might be well served by the new ON CONFLICT operation but for now you might want to look into a trigger. Specifically a BEFORE INSERT that UPDATEs the count (if the product exists) and then returns NULL to indicate that the INSERT should not continue. I strongly suspect you will have to address concurrency (race-conditions) as well, probably at the application level.

For information on triggers see [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the PostgreSQL docs.

Comment: A trigger can only do this safely if you `LOCK` the table in `EXCLUSIVE` mode first.